# "git init" via "gio mount" on samba: fatal: could not set 'core.filemode' to 'false'

Tags: samba, git, mount, gnome

I want to push my repository to a Samba share mounted via GNOME's Nautilus. I believe it uses *gio mount* under the hood. However, when I try to run *git init* in a mounted Samba share, I get the following error:

```
error: chmod on /run/user/1000/gvfs/smb-share:server=myserver,share=myshare,user=myuser/project_dir/.git/config.lock failed: Operation not supported
fatal: could not set 'core.filemode' to 'false'
```

How do I fix this, so that I can push to this directory?

Comment: gvfs really only works well (or at all) with GNOME tools like Nautilus. Try mounting the filesystem normally instead.

Comment: That’s probably the solution that I will use, but the answer to the actual question might be much more interesting for others, so I will keep it open until someone comes along :)

Answer (score 1):

Just an idea (not tested): try `git config --global core.filemode false` to change is globally and then `git init` on your samba dir again.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work. I've even tried to run "git init" in another dir and then copying things over, but then I get slightly different errors when trying to push. I guess it's filesystem related, so this question might be interesting to others as well :)